# change the color of margins/background of text_field_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have the a text_field_tag, where a user can type a number. If he typed a smt but not the number, the color of background or margins of text_field_tag should change to the red.
here I check if I have some errors:

```
 <%
  error_tuning="controls"
  if !errors.nil?
errors.each do |er|                                 
  if pk3 == er[1] and row == er[0]
   error_tuning = "error_info_update"
  end
    end
 end
 %>
```

And here I choose what div class I should use, a normal one ("controls") or a changed one ("error_info_update")

```
<td>    
<div class="<%=error_tuning%>">                            
    <%= text_field_tag "number", cell_val['value_number'],  :class => "table_column_width", :placeholder => t(val_type) %> 
</div>
```

my css:

```
.error_info_update {
    background-color: #FF0000;  
}
```

The problem is that it does not color the whole background/margins but somehow only the right line of the text_field_tag.

Thanks in advance
Tonja

Answer (score 0):

had to change css to:

```
background-color: #FF0000;  
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
width:116px;
```